# Is there a way to have a big list for autocompletion discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

For this autocompletion code -

```
async def drink_autocompletion(
    interaction: discord.Interaction,
    current: str
) -> typing.List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
    data = []
    for drink_choice in ['beer', 'milk', 'tea', 'coffee', 'juice']:
        if current.lower() in drink_choice.lower():
            data.append(app_commands.Choice(name=drink_choice, value=drink_choice))
    return data
```

is there a way so you could replace the 'beer', 'milk', 'tea', 'coffee', 'juice' with another file full of items? For example you could have another document will more items could you import it and put it there instead of having a huge list?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't see why that wouldn't be possible. You just need to return a list of some sort, how you get it there is irrelevant. You can import whatever you want, perform database queries, make API calls, open files, access attributes of class instances, ... Save your list however & wherever you want.

Just keep in mind that this gets triggered every time someone types a character, so if it's *really* big you may want to just cache it upon startup.